# Scrolling to offset for SectionList in ReactNative

Tags: react-native, react-native-sectionlist

Is there a way to scroll based on offset rather than scrollToLocation for a Section List?

Currently, it only allows the scrolling to a specific section/index.

Also would there be a clever way to control the speed of the scrolling animation?

Comment: I still have this issue, were you able to find a way around it?